# Menu Ordering differences due to Fragment and Activity hierarchy. (onCreateOptionsMenu)

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, android-fragments

**Background**

Developing for Android 3.0, I have a `HostActivity` that is the superclass of `NotebooksActivity` and `NoteActivity`. `NotebooksActivity` includes a fragment, `NotebooksFragment`.

In `HostActivity`, I include a menu that I want to appear at the rightmost end of the options menu in the ActionBar, **i.e. all menu items in subclasses of `HostActivity` should appear to the left of the menu items added in `HostActivity`.**

Menu inflation in `HostActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.host_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**The Problem**

When I add menu items in `NoteActivity`, I achieve the desired order as expected:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.notebook_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

However, when I add menu items in `NotebooksFragment`, because of how Fragments work, `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called after the same method in `HostActivity`, **resulting in `HostActivity`'s menu items appearing before `NotebooksFragment`'s.**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.notebooks_menu, menu);
    SearchView sv = new SearchView(getActivity());
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    menu.findItem(R.id.search_notebooks).setActionView(sv);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

How can I achieve my desired menu ordering?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try using `android:menuCategory` and `android:orderInCategory` to more manually specify your ordering.

Or, use `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` in `HostActivity`, as that is called after `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. Downside is that it is called on every MENU button press, not just the first time.

Comment: I tried out the onPrepareOptionsMenu() method, and it worked. It was being called twice on my Xoom for some reason, however, so I had to add a little extra code to prevent duplicates.

Comment: I solved this problem, using `android:menuCategory` and `android:orderInCategory`.

I tried adding the fragment menu items by code, but didn't work, so I was forced to use an XML menu :(

Comment: For me it was enough to add `android:menuCategory="secondary"` to the activity items which should appear at the end of the mehu. An extra ordering attribute was not required.